# hiding an id variable using cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm a bit new so sorry for the probably stupid question, I have an app which lists users of my site. Other users of the site can click on the name of another user that brings them to a contact page where they can then contact the user they clicked on.

I want to be able to keep the user_id's of the person being contacted private for the meantime. I know I can get the id of the currently logged in user, but I need to also know the id of the recipient. The only way I know to do this would involve passing the id of the person to be contacted in the url or in a hidden form variable, both of which are viewable one way or another.

Is there another way to do this where I don't have to make the id of the user to be contacted visable?

thanks

Comment: if you don't want something seen by a user, then don't send it to the user in the first place. at least not in something trivially readable as a "hidden" form field. keep the private data on the server in a session. if you HAVE to round-trip it through the client. at least encrypt/obfuscate the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign it a random unique id, that will be indexed on the session, to the real id. it will be deleted after the session ends.